# Is this the correct way to use an array of abstract class (C++)?

Tags: c++, class, pointers, polymorphism, abstract-class

## Ignore the fact that I using raw pointers/arrays.

I am making a card game in C++ that has a `Player` abstract class that is extended by other classes. I need to make an array of pointers to these derived classes. This works, but is there a better way?

```
class Player{
   public:
        Player();
        Player(const Player&);
        Player & operator=(const Player &);

        virtual void sort() = 0;
        virtual Card play(Pile*) = 0;

        void confirmPlay();

        void giveHand(Hand&);
        void giveCard(Card);
        bool hasCards();

        void won();
        void resetWins();
        int getWins();

        virtual ~Player();
    protected:
        int cardsLeft;
        Hand hand;
        int cardPlayed;
        int wins;
    private:
};

class DumbPlayer : public Player
{
    public:
        DumbPlayer();
        Card play(Pile*);
        void sort();
        virtual ~DumbPlayer();
        DumbPlayer & operator=(const DumbPlayer &);
        DumbPlayer(const DumbPlayer&);
    protected:
    private:
};

class Game{
    public:
        Game(int,  Player**&);
        void playX(int);
        void playOne();
        virtual ~Game();
    protected:
    private:
        bool done();
        Game & operator=(const Game &);
        Game(const Game&);
        Pile * piles;
        Deck deck;
        int playerCount;
        Player ** players;
};

//implementation not shown to save space, tell me if you would like to see anything.
//I think that all of the other class/function names should be good enough to not show.

Game::Game(const int pplayerCount, Player**& pplayers) : 
                                   piles(new Pile[4]), 
                                   playerCount(pplayerCount), 
                                   deck(), 
                                   players(new Player*[playerCount]){
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        piles[i].setSuit(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < playerCount; i++){
        players[i] = pplayers[i];
    }
}

void Game::playOne(){
    deck.shuffle();  //shuffle deck
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        piles[i].reset();  //reset piles
    }
    Hand hands[playerCount];  //create hands
    Hand leftovers;
    deck.dealAll(playerCount, hands, leftovers); //deal the deck
    int cardsLeftover = leftovers.getSize();     //there are leftover cards, 
                                                 //52/3 has a remainder
    for(int playerIdx = 0; playerIdx < playerCount; playerIdx++){
        (*players[playerIdx]).giveHand(hands[playerIdx]); //this is what 
                                                          //i am unsure about.
        (*players[playerIdx]).sort();
    }
    int winner = -1;
    while(!done()){
        for(int playerIdx = 0; playerIdx < playerCount; playerIdx++){
            Card play = (*players[playerIdx]).play(piles);
            if(piles[play.getSuit()].canPut(play)){
                (*players[playerIdx]).confirmPlay();
                piles[play.getSuit()].put(play);
                if(!(*players[playerIdx]).hasCards()){
                    winner = playerIdx;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                if(cardsLeftover > 0){
                    (*players[playerIdx]).giveCard(leftovers.popCard(--cardsLeftover));
                }
            }
        }
        if(winner != -1){
            (*players[winner]).won();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that it is a ton of code (for this site)... i am unsure about the game constructor/class and the lines including `(*players[i]).x()`

Comment: Don't use raw pointers. Don't use raw arrays. Do use standard library elements.

Comment: I'm still unclear on your question, but if you're just upset about the `(*players[i].x())` syntax, you can clean it up a little by saying `players[i]->x()` instead.  Other than that, your comment on ignoring the fact that you're using raw pointers & arrays is a bit misguided IMHO--you asked us what you could do to improve your code, and smart pointers & vectors are a big part of what you could do to make it more robust.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nowadays, an array of pointers is spelled:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<Player> > players;
```

This takes full of the [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII) idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to ensure destructors are called properly and memory is reclaimed in the face of exceptions and unforeseen code paths.

Comment: Prefer boost::ptr_vector<T> it not only manages the pointers. But it exposes its elements as references to the object. Thus using it with the standard algorithms is much simpler.

Comment: I always forget about the ptr_containers.  Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Why is this better? Aren't the destructors always called after an exception? or are they not?

Comment: Sure, but the destructors for the pointers (i.e. no-ops) rather than the destructors of the pointed-to objects.  Not to mention no delete to free up the memory used.  std::vector puts deallocation logic for the array in its destructor, while boost::shared_ptr puts the delete/destroy logic for the pointed too object in its destructor.

Comment: @Drew Accepted for your comment on the main question, that was what i was asking. I will also use the std::vector/boost::shared_ptr

Answer (score 1):

Use std::vector, list, map etc.